# Como usar a sintaxe HTML dentro do Markdown do Github para mostrar código em highlight?

Tags: html, github, markdown

No Github é possível mostrar um código highlight com sintaxe em Markdown, da seguinte forma (considere a aspas simples sendo o acento grave `):

```
Este é meu arquivo README.md

'''dart
void main() {
 // Este é meu código em highlight para a linguagem Dart
}
'''
```

Ou seja, no Mardown usamos três acentos graves para indicar o início do código highlight, e três para indicar o final. Mas como eu faço isso sem ser utilizando essa sintaxe de Markdown e sim a de HTML?

```
Este é meu arquivo README.md

<pre>
  <code>
    void main(){
      // Meu código em highlight para linguagem Dart mas em sintaxe HTML dentro do markdown
    }
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

A resposta dessa pergunta é simples, não há uma forma de aplicar uma "sintaxe HTML" dentro do Markdown para código highlight no Github. A única forma é a que você mencionou, que é utilizando o acento agudo (`).

Se você precisa colocar um código com sintaxe highlight dentro de um Markdown com código HTML, por exemplo, um `details`, basta dar uma linha de espaço entre o código HTML e os acentos agudos, ou seja, ficaria desta forma (considere a aspas simples sendo o acento grave `):

```dart
<details>
  <summary>Seu código HTML dentro do arquivo markdown</summary>

'''dart
void main() {
  // Código com sintaxe highlight não muda, independente se está dentro do HTML ou fora.
}
'''
</details>
```